# How to create a rule for a contact group/distribution list in order to move emails to a certain folder for Outlook 2013?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, email-client, outlook-addin

I created a rule for a contact group/distribution list in order to move emails to a certain folder. It works without any problems. Let's call this group **'distgroup'.**

However, for some emails that comes to the **group email(distgroup)**, '**To**' and '**From**' fields are **same** as **'From'**. Normally **'To'** field is supposed to be **'distrgroup'**.

Because of this, when I cannot run the same rule for this type of emails since group email address is not written in either 'To' or 'From'. It doesn't move that emails to my certain folder.

Is there any solutions about it?

Header

> Received: from cluster08.natrohost.com (xxx) by
>   xxxxx (xxx) with Microsoft SMTP Server id
>   xxxx; Fri, 25 Oct 2013  10:28:27 +0300 Received: with MailEnable
>   Postoffice Connector; Fri, 25 Oct 2013 10:29:33  +0300 Received: from
>   liste.tubitak.gov.tr ([xxx9]) by natrohost.com with  MailEnable ESMTP;
>   Fri, 25 Oct 2013 10:29:27 +0300 Received: from listeler.tubitak.gov.tr
>   (localhost [127.0.0.1])   by  liste.tubitak.gov.tr (Postfix) with ESMTP
>   id 5BD2E802E31;   Fri, 25 Oct 2013  10:27:02 +0300 (EEST) X-Original-To:
>   teydeb.duyuru@liste.tubitak.gov.tr Delivered-To:
>   teydeb.duyuru@liste.tubitak.gov.tr Received: from sg02.tubitak.gov.tr
>   (mta.tubitak.gov.tr [193.140.13.205]) by  liste.tubitak.gov.tr
>   (Postfix) with ESMTP id 71D82802E30   for 
>   ; Fri, 25 Oct 2013 10:18:12 +0300
>   (EEST) Received: (surgate 55085 invoked by uid 1001); 25 Oct 2013
>   07:18:12 -0000 Received: from unknown (HELO mta01.tubitak.gov.tr)
>   (xxx) by 0 with   SMTP; 25 Oct 2013 07:18:11 -0000 Received: from
>   localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])by mta01.tubitak.gov.tr  (Postfix)
>   with ESMTP id 663A032070Afor  ;
>     Fri, 25 Oct 2013 10:18:11 +0300 (EEST) X-Virus-Scanned: amavisd-new
>   at mta01.tubitak.gov.tr Received: from mta01.tubitak.gov.tr
>   ([127.0.0.1])by localhost     (mta01.tubitak.gov.tr [127.0.0.1])
>   (amavisd-new, port    10026)with ESMTP id  JHLc51rvBzb3
>   for   ;   Fri, 25 Oct 2013  10:18:11
>   +0300 (EEST) Received: from mail02.tubitak.gov.tr (mail02.tubitak.gov.tr [10.250.10.220])by   mta01.tubitak.gov.tr
>   (Postfix) with ESMTP id BE81F320705for
>     ;   Fri, 25 Oct 2013 10:18:10 +0300
>   (EEST) Date: Fri, 25 Oct 2013 10:18:10 +0300 From: TEYDEB Duyuru
>    To: teydeb duyuru
>    Message-ID:
>   <1587320322.330653.1382685490563.JavaMail.root@tubitak.gov.tr>
>   In-Reply-To:
>   <1729353344.306519.1382680469289.JavaMail.root@tubitak.gov.tr>
>   References:
>   <306399992.14028065.1382433976299.JavaMail.root@tubitak.gov.tr>
>     <2044554093.14121570.1382458462140.JavaMail.root@tubitak.gov.tr>
>     <929390811.14153310.1382507750321.JavaMail.root@tubitak.gov.tr>
>     <1729353344.306519.1382680469289.JavaMail.root@tubitak.gov.tr>
>   MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
>     boundary="----=_Part_330649_550081700.1382685490539"
>   X-Originating-IP: [xxx] X-Mailer: Zimbra 8.0.0_GA_5434
>   (ZimbraWebClient - FF24 (Win)/8.0.0_GA_5434) Thread-Topic: firma
>   =?utf-8?Q?ba=C5=9Far=C4=B1_puan=C4=B1_-_ileti=C5=9Fim?=   bilgisi Thread-Index: ee2kjcbAgV1nReKghS9jOkg9b6ioV5D6CcE2W3p0Yh1e4CN3NO5jM6Zx
>   X-SMTP-Filter: SurGATE SMTP Filter EngineRelease 4.0 ($Revision: 523
>   $) X-SurGATE-Result: Clean (Content eval: 0.00 points)
>   X-SurGATE-Reason: WHITELIST match: teydeb.duyuru@tubitak.gov.tr
>   [pattern:     @tubitak.gov.tr$] X-Mailman-Approved-At: Fri, 25 Oct 2013
>   10:27:00 +0300 Subject: [Teydeb.duyuru]
>   =?utf-8?b?RmlybWEgQmHFn2FyxLEgUHVhbsSx?= X-BeenThere: teydeb.duyuru@liste.tubitak.gov.tr X-Mailman-Version: 2.1.12
>   Precedence: list Reply-To:  List-Id:
>    List-Unsubscribe:
>   http://mail.liste.tubitak.gov.tr/mailman/options/teydeb.duyuru,
>     
>   List-Archive:
>   http://mail.liste.tubitak.gov.tr/pipermail/teydeb.duyuru/ List-Post:
>    List-Help:
>   
>   List-Subscribe:
>   http://mail.liste.tubitak.gov.tr/mailman/listinfo/teydeb.duyuru,
>     
>   Sender:  Errors-To:
>   teydeb.duyuru-bounces@liste.tubitak.gov.tr Received-SPF: pass
>   (natrohost.com: domain of liste.tubitak.gov.tr designates xxx as
>   permitted sender)     client-ip=xxxx X-Envelope-Sender:
>   teydeb.duyuru-bounces@liste.tubitak.gov.tr X-ME-Bayesian: 40.000000
>   Return-Path: teydeb.duyuru-bounces@liste.tubitak.gov.tr
>   X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: xxxx
>   X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous X-Auto-Response-Suppress:
>   DR, OOF, AutoReply

**I have an idea to resolve this but ı am not sure how I can do it.
If somehow I can set a rule such as if my name is not in To field and CC Field, move the mails to the specific folder.**

This may be the solution. But I don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I still think the best to do is to use the List-Unsubscribe header, as your last idea describe you could use the **except** rule.

On the Rules Wizard, select Move messages from someone to a folder and click Next:

[image]

On the conditions, unselect "from people or public group", click Next and Yes on the pop-up question:

[image]

On actions, specify the destination folder, and select Next:

[image]

Now you select the exception and click Next:

[image]

Save your new rule, click Finish:

[image]

Your final rule would look like:

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
move it to MyFolder folder
except where my name is not in the To box
stop processing more rules
```

Answer (score 0):

It feels to me that although the messages don't have **From** header different from the **To** header, the **Subject** always include the words *[Teydeb.duyuru]* so consider filtering using it:

1. Select File, Manage Rules & Alerts.
2. Click the New Rule button.
3. On the "Step 1: Select a template" box, under the section labeled "Start from a blank rule", select Apply rule on messages I receive.
4. Click Next.
5. In the "Which condition(s) do you want to check?" box, check the box with specific words in the subject.
6. In the "Edit the Rule Description" box below, click on specific words.
7. In the "Specify words or phrases to search for in this subject" window, type the text to search for. In your case you would type `[Teydeb.duyuru]`
8. Click the Add button. Click OK. Click Next.

Continue the steps as you already did to move the message to a different folder.

If that does not work for all the messages you could follow the same steps and search for one of the headers you just copied over (i.e: type exactly this: `List-Unsubscribe: http://mail.liste.tubitak.gov.tr/mailman/options/teydeb.duyuru` )
The search mechanism should work for the entire message body, not only the parts we normally see.

Comment: This was only an example of one of the emails. [Teydeb.duyuru] is the name of the newsletter. It will vary depending on the email. So, yo cannot relate it with a rule.

Comment: Also I updated my question with an idea. Please check it out.

Comment: have you tried using the List-unsubscribe header? I bet it is on all emails, isn't it?